# Laravel Bootstrap ui

Tags: node.js, laravel, composer-php, laravel-10, bootstrap-ui

Experiencing this error trying to run `npm run dev`. I'm trying to use bootstrap ui for a laravel project.

Tried installing the latest version of nodejs but still couldn't figure it out.
Also `cleared cash` but still getting this after running `npm run dev`

```
wolf@wolf-HP-ProBook-430-G3:/var/www/html/Hospital$ npm run dev

> dev
> vite

file:///var/www/html/Hospital/node_modules/vite/bin/vite.js:7
await import('source-map-support').then((r) =\> r.default.install())
^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:133:18)
at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:42:21)
```

Comment: Please share more details. How is this problem related to Composer? If it is not, please remove the tag